# how to find the source of mail (host<->lxc container)

Tags: iptables, email-server, hacking

One of my lxc-containers is mail server. the others and the host use it to communicate with the world.
But something is using my mail server to sending mails. I found, that mail server receives it from the host. But the mail server on host is doing nothing - on log there is one mail on hour or less. So, there is a other mail server on host, which is connecting to lxc-container and is sending mails.

I wonder if my lxc-host is compromised (and nothing but new server helps) or i make a hole in firewall and it is just some kind of open relay. 
before detecting this there is no sense to making new server with the same setting.

I wonder if I set some iptables rule on host which will log any motion on dest port 25 or 587 - but is possible to log it with process id or better name?

Or maybe some proxy on host?

Comment: All sensible MTAs will log from where an incoming message has come, so check the mail server's log.

Comment: well, lxc-container MTA logs that from lxc-host... this isn't solution to block lxc-host from sending mails.. I need to find what on lxc-host sends mails, while it isn't MTA on lxc-host.